# Definir Espaço para texto

Tags: cmd, batch

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se existe algum comando do cmd para definir um espaço fixo para o texto, de forma que não alterasse a posição do resto da frase.

No exemplo abaixo esse espaço é o * ㅤ ㅤ ㅤ*

Meu nome é * Carlos ㅤ ㅤ ㅤ*, aqui entra o resto da frase 
Meu nome é * João vitor ㅤ ㅤ*, aqui entra o resto da frase 
Meu nome é * Alexssandra ㅤ *, aqui entra o resto da frase

Answer (score 2):

Você pode compor a sua string concatenando as duas primeiras partes, adicionando os espaços, pegar um substring e adicionar o final. veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "espaco=                       "
set "prefixo=Meu nome é"
set "frase= ,aqui entra o resto da frase"

set "nome=Carlos"
set "linha1=%prefixo% %nome%%espaco%"
set "linha1=%linha1:~0,24% %frase%

set "nome=João Vitor"
set "linha2=%prefixo% %nome%%espaco%"
set "linha2=%linha2:~0,24% %frase%

set "nome=Alexssandra"
set "linha3=%prefixo% %nome%%espaco%"
set "linha3=%linha3:~0,24% %frase%

echo %linha1%  & echo %linha2%  & echo %linha3%
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]